# iOS - Custom camera view with a timed delay

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I've found a lot of information on custom camera views, but nothing about showing the camera view delayed.

For example, I'd like to display a camera view in a `UIView`, but from X seconds ago.

Is there a straight forward way to do this? Or do I need to record video and play it back X seconds later?

I've actually posted a much more detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892328/ios-creating-multiple-time-delayed-live-camera-preview-views).

Comment: There may be a way to delay the video from the camera and display it on screen after a lag... but I would assume that would take a dramatic amount of memory and would be a giant pain in the neck. I think that your best bet is to record the video and play it back.

Comment: @Jake Either way, I run into an issue of how to store the data. I want an indefinite stream of delayed video to display in multiple views (i.e. 5s delay, 20s delay, and 60s delay, in 3 separate views, for example). I haven't yet found viable solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Creating multiple time-delayed live camera preview views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892328/ios-creating-multiple-time-delayed-live-camera-preview-views)